# WebApi queries on nonexistent resource returns 200

Tags: sitecore-api, item-web-api

I am using the Sitecore 7.2 Item Web API to retrieve some items. Using fast queries I am not able get a "404" in case  an item doesn't exist (even if i don't use fast queries, i still don't get 404).   All I get is a blank json response with  "200" response.   Any ideas why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Fast query](https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/developer/using%20sitecore%20fast%20query/using%20sitecore%20fast%20query001.pdf) does not equal to [web request](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html). It should not return same codes.

You can execute fast query from Item Web API, from code, from XPath builder. And for these three places fast queries should work in a same way. I think that it would have no sense get 404 error when executing query code or XPath builder. 404 is response code for web `Not Found`. 404 response would mean that resource was not found, in other words: Item Web API endpoint that should execute your request was not found.

200 is response code `OK`. It means that your fast query was successfully executed and you can find result(s) in response(if any).

P.S.:
To understand why this behavior is better, let's imagine that it would return 404 code as you wish. How would you define what happened:

- No items were found during execution of query
- Query was not executed. For some reason URL your_host/-/item/v1/?scope=c&query=your_query was not found.